# Will visual studio 2008 express support Multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio

Will visual studio 2008 express support Multithreading ? I dont have an option to upgrade it . Is it possible with 2008 version ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not moving to the Visual Studio Community edition? It is a full blown compiler and is free in most instances

Comment: I dont have the admin privilege  to install new version.I will get the admin privilege next week.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, definitely

I used Visual Studio 2008 for a large C++ code base and threads worked, no problem. C++11 like thread features are also available through TR1 (if you SP1 installed).

There should be no problem with any of the other languages, I'm sure.